# Grizzly: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers

Tags: jersey-2.0, grizzly

I am using Grizzly/Jersey/Jackson in a RESTful web service server application.  For certain interactions, a large number of HTTP headers may be returned in a response.  By default, Grizzy sets a maxium number of response headers to 100.

Reading the Grizzy [Http Server Framework Overview](https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html), it seems like the **maxResponseHeaders** (*maximum number of headers a response may send to a client*) can somehow be configured, but it's not clear how that is done when Grizzly is stacked up with Jersey.

Any suggestions on what to try to set this configuration?

This is how I am currently configuring Grizzly and Jackson:

```
packages(true, Config.CONFIG_RESOURCE_BASE_PACKAGE);
register(JacksonFeature.class);
register(GrizzlyHttpContainerProvider.class);
register(CustomInjectables.class);
register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
register(AccessSecurityFilter.class);

String host = Config.get("webserver.address");
int port = Config.getInteger("webserver.port");
boolean secure = Config.getBoolean("webserver.secure");

if (secure) {
    SSLContextConfigurator sslContextConfigurator = new SSLContextConfigurator();
    sslContextConfigurator.setKeyStoreFile(Config
            .get("webserver.keystore.location"));
    sslContextConfigurator.setKeyStorePass(Config
            .get("webserver.keystore.password"));

    boolean clientMode = false;
    boolean needClientAuth = false;
    boolean wantClientAuth = false;
    SSLEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SSLEngineConfigurator(
            sslContextConfigurator, clientMode, needClientAuth,
            wantClientAuth);

    URI uri = URI.create("https://" + host + ":" + port);
    log.info("Starting web server (secure): " + uri + " ...");
    server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, this, true,
            sslEngineConfigurator, true);
} else {
    URI uri = URI.create("http://" + host + ":" + port);
    log.info("Starting web server: " + uri + " ...");
    server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, this, true);
}
```

This is the stack when I exceed the maximum number of response headers:

```
Apr 24, 2017 10:28:46 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain execute
WARNING: GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders$MaxHeaderCountExceededException: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpServerFilter.prepareResponse(HttpServerFilter.java:944)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpServerFilter.encodeHttpPacket(HttpServerFilter.java:834)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpCodecFilter.handleWrite(HttpCodecFilter.java:1407)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:858)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1029)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBinaryBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:1016)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushAllBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:987)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:716)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOWriterImpl.close(NIOWriterImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.util.HtmlHelper.sendErrorPage(HtmlHelper.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:1358)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer$ResponseWriter.failure(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firs thing you need to do is have the server *not* automatically start when you call [`createHttpServer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html#createHttpServer(java.net.URI,%20org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig,%20boolean)). Currently, you are passing `true` as the last argument, which is saying that is *should* auto-start. This configuration is already the default. So it's mainly used to set the value to `false`, meaning *don't* auto-start. So set that value to `false`.

Now that the server is not auto-starting, we can configure it. The specific configuration of the `setMaxResponseHeader` is a configuration on the [`NetworkListener`](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/NetworkListener.html). You can get that from the `HttpServer`.

```
final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(...);
final NetworkListener listener = server.getListener("grizzly");
listener.setMaxResponseHeaders(300);
server.start();
```

Now we manually start the server after configuration. The one thing I'm not sure about if there is a better way to get the listener. I just hard coded the `"grizzly"` because what I did prior was just iterate through `server.getListeners()` and print out all the names, and saw that `"grizzly"` was the only one available. So that's what I used to test.

Aside from the `NetworkListener` configuration, there are also other server related configurations you can make through the [`ServerConfiguration`](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/ServerConfiguration.html). You can get the with `server.getServerConfiguration()`